# Filing the W-8BEN as a working professional on an F-1 visa

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-8-ben

I am an Indian citizen currently residing and working in the US.

I am working for a company while on an F-1 visa (on my STEM OPT), having graduated 2 years ago. I had a few questions regarding filing the W-8BEN:

Q1) For section 3 (Permanent address), the instructions say:

> Your permanent residence address is the address in the country where
> you claim to be a resident for purposes of that country’s income tax.

Since I am on an F-1 visa, I do not qualify for the substantial presence test and so I am a non-resident alien. Does that mean that I should fill the address of my home country (India) ?

Q2) Do I leave 'reference number' blank?

Comment: "Since I am on an F-1 visa, I do not qualify for the substantial presence test and so I am a non-resident alien." This is not necessarily true. If you have been on F1 for some part of 5 previous calendar years, then your days on F1 this year *are* counted in the Substantial Presence Test.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks for pointing this out. I have been in the US for just under 3 years and have been on F-1 all through that period. In that case I should not qualify for the SPT, right?

Comment: Right, assuming you have never been in F, J, M, or Q status before these 3 years.